# How to restore chat history between two users from Openfire server using Smack in android app

Tags: android, openfire, smack

Hi I have installed an configured OpenFire and doing text messaging in android app successfully.I need to restore chat history from Openfire server .Any suggetion will be appreciated.

Comment: for one to one you can get only some messages, when to connect that user.

Comment: you can't get all previous messages.

Answer (score 0):

Open fire does not support restore messages if a message reaches the receiver that will automatically purged from server .If receiver is offline the openfire will keep the message for a specific time period .

Thanks